# Returning the first element python

Tags: python

I have a list/tuple/array of `S1 = (15, 20, 65)`
I want to loop through this list/tuple/array and get the first element which is `15`

What i've done is:

```
for sensor in S1:
    print (sensor[0])
```

However i got the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Then, I tried the following code:

```
for sensor in S1:
    print (str(sensor)[0])
```

but it prints all of the first digit of the numbers.

How can I get the result `15` (the first element)?

Comment: If you have `Test= (15, 20, 65)`, you just have to type `print(Test[0])` for the first element. You don't need for loop

Comment: drop the `[0]` from the value

Comment: No need to loop, just print S1[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, lets clarify: your variable `S1` is a tuple. Lists go in square brackets.

Your loop over `S1` is saying "for each element in this tuple, print that element's first element". This means that it's going to try to subscript each integer value, which isn't possible.

The reason that it works when you first convert each element to a string is that strings are subscriptable, they give you the character at the index you supply.

From reading your question I'm not sure if you want the first item in a tuple that is equal to 15, or if you just want the first item, which happens to be 15 in this case.

The former:

```
def get_15(t):
  for el in t:
    if el == 15:
      return el
  return -1

get_15((1, 2, 3, 15))  # => 15
get_15((1, 2, 3))  # => -1
```

The latter:

```
def get_first(t):
  return t[0]

get_first((1, 2, 3))  # 1
get_first((3, 2, 1))  # 3
```

Answer (score 2):

S1[0] gives you the first element.

Your first code doesn't work because when you loop through S1, sensor is already an integer, and then sensor[0] doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

This works. It prints 15

```
S1 = [15, 20, 65]

print(S1[0])
```