# How do I get arrays to couple multiple numbers?

Tags: python, arrays, tkinter

I'm making a game with a saving system in Python, but it doesn't work as intended.

```
thingcount = saveArray[0]
```

The code above is supposed to set thingcount to **5454**, as shown in the saveArray:

```
[5454, 0, 1]
```

But it only sets `thingcount` to **5**. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: So, `saveArray = [5454,0,1]`? If that is indeed the case then `thingcount= saveArray[0]` would set `thingcount` to 5454. If it doesn't, then `saveArray` is not equal to `[5454,0,1]`.
I could suspect that it is strings instead of integers and you try to access the first element of the string `"5454"` in some way (e.g if that is not the full code you provide)

Comment: Yep, the save array is [5454, 0, 1]. `thingcount` is an integer if that helps. That is if an integer is a number, which I'm 100% sure it is.

Comment: I can assure you if `saveArray = [5454,0,1]` and you write `thingcount=saveArray[0]` then `savearray` will be `5454`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As some of the comments have noted, if `saveArray` truly equals `[5454, 0, 1]`, then the command `print(thingcount)` will yield your desired output of `[5454]`

If `thingcount[0]` yields an output of `5`, then at some point in your code, `saveArray` is being set to `5454` only - Maybe as a string, but not the full list of `[5454, 0, 1]`

Below are two code snippets for a comparison example:

**Desired Output**

```
saveArray = [5454, 0, 1]
thingcount = saveArray[0]

print (thingcount)
```

**Console output:**

```
5454
```

**Code that will yield the output you're seeing**

```
saveArray = '5454'
thingcount = saveArray[0]

print (thingcount)
```

**Console output:**

```
5
```

In any case, I would check what `saveArray` is being set to - At some point in your code, its being set to a different value, not your full target list of `[5454,0,1]`

On getting the first element from a list in Python - Below is a link to another thread that discusses getting the first element of a list, if that is helpful:

[Returning the first element python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093175/returning-the-first-element-python)